# Not posting in database

Tags: php, file-upload

I am not getting any error. But image which I am uploading is not saving in `images/photo/` directory.
I see in my database is there any problem in it? 
Please help me..thank you. and sorry for disturbing i'm just new in PHP language.

Here's my code in saving:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    addpost($_POST['fname'], $_POST['cont'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['add'], $_POST['description'], $_FILES["image"] ["name"], $_FILES["image"] ["type"], $_FILES["image"] ["size"], $_FILES["image"] ["tmp_name"], $_FILES["image"] ["error"]);
    echo $success = "<script language='javascript' >
    alert('Your Post has been successfuly added!')
    window.location='post.php'
    </script>";
}
?>
```

And here's my code in connect.php :

```
function addpost($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $name, $type, $size, $tmp_name, $error) {
    $img = 'images/posts/' . $name;
    mysql_query("INSERT post(p_name,p_contact,p_email,p_address,description,photo,dateadded) values 
('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$img',NOW())");

    if ($error > 0) {
        die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
    } else {
        if ($size > 10000000000) {
            die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/posts/" . $name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u add the code of the form that u have ..

Comment: this code? <form action=""  method="post" onSubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">

Comment: The problem is the one that @AbhikChakraborty pointed out in his answer. But please note: you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for file upload you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the form so your form should be as

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">
```

Comment: Hello, is there any chance that i can upload 2 images using different <input name="image"> & <input name="image2"> and how can i insert the second one? Thank You.

Comment: Yes you can upload multiple files.. check here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php